# React button that authenticates with json and conditionally renders

Tags: json, function, reactjs, button, conditional-statements

I have am trying to create a button in React that does "if '/backend_authentication' returns true, then continue into next page, or else don't continue into next page". how do I do this?

Note: I am just wondering how to code the button to do this. I don't need to change the fetch.

```
class Login extends Component {

handleClick(event) {
fetch('/backend_authentication')
.then(res => res.json())
}

render() {
return (
<div>       
         <LinkContainer to='/Homepage'>
             <Button onClick={this.handleClick} 
               type="submit"> /> 
              </Button>
         </LinkContainer>
</div>
);
}
}
```

Comment: @uğuraydın why? `fetch` is just fine... OP doesn't need a completely different package to accomplish what they're looking for.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how to code this if statement, not changing the fetch

Comment: Just for suggestion and it has awesome features that fits to your task.

Comment: It looks like you're using react-router, so take a look here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score 0):

When you request for authentication you will probably receive some response object, Hence, check the response data for success or failure like
if(response.status==ok)
then redirect to next dashboard page ; else ask for credentials again